# Read CustomXmlParts VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto

I tried to find any materials on the web without any sucess is it possible to read or add custom xmlparts without opening workbook in vsto ? I know how to add them when i open a workbook.

Comment: You can use the EpPlus open source library that is able to read, write, create excel workbooks or you can use the OpenXml .Net Libraries, (DocumentFormat.OpenXml) that you can find in the Open Xml sdk 2.5 downloadable online. EpPlus is a wrapper to make more "edible" the OpenXml library for excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Open XML SDK for that. Here is the example for Word that can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb456489.aspx# but should be relatively easy to change WordprocessingDocument into SpreadsheetDocument and do what you need to do.

```
public static void AddNewPart(string document, string fileName)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

        CustomXmlPart myXmlPart = mainPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            myXmlPart.FeedData(stream);
        }
    }
}
```